# Is it necessary to develop Pages separately for the Mobile access and browser access

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, web-applications

We need to develop a Finance Application in Java J2EE which can be accessed from any client that is ( A mobile or Browser )
We need to use  technologies like HTML , JSP , Servlets , EJB , Hibernate .

Please let me know is it necessary to develop Pages separately for the Mobile access and browser access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for is adaptative and responsive design, you will be mostly dealing with frontend. Boagworld has some nice contents and a great podcast on the subject

http://boagworld.com/dev/a-case-study-in-responsive-design/

Answer (score 0):

You could have the backend entirely in java. And use jQuery mobile/bootstrap in the frontend. That way the application should work well in mobile browsers. Also using Ajax and having server compute all most everything should give you a very performing app in mobile browsers. Also checkout chrome emulation mode it should help in development and testing the responsive behavior